# Editing SharedPreferences in Android based on user input

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm very new to Java/Android development and I'm trying to simply have a user check a radio button for "boy" or "girl" and have it written to `SharedPreferences` so I can use it in other activities. Whenever I try and open this activity, but my app just crashes.

```
public class NewBabyProfile extends Activity {

String GENDER = "Baby1Gender"; 

// SharedPreferences initializations
SharedPreferences babyOneGender = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = babyOneGender.edit();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_baby_profile, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View genderSelection){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) genderSelection).isChecked();

    switch(genderSelection.getId()) {
        case R.id.gender_boy:
            if (checked)
                editor.putString("gender","boy").commit();
            break;

        case R.id.gender_girl:
            if (checked)
                editor.putString("gender","girl").commit();
            break;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you move out the initialization of `babyOneGender` and `editor` inside the `OnCreate` method, and see what happens?

Comment: When I do that errors that "editor can't be resolved" in the switch down below.

Comment: Please provide the error for the crash from the log

Comment: Sure!



'10-09 21:43:19.407: E/AndroidRuntime(3263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 21:43:19.407: E/AndroidRuntime(3263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parentingreminders/com.example.parentingreminders.NewBabyProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: Post your whole activity with NewB‌​abyProfile.

Comment: That is the whole activity as of now.

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot. I posted it in the onRadioButton() class and it seems to have worked. Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize following two directly in a class.

```
SharedPreferences babyOneGender = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = babyOneGender.edit();
```

Your SharedPreferences initializations should happen inside a method like onCreate() or onResume()
Move this into onCreate(Bundle) and your app won't crash again. Also check your logcat to find out the problem yourself :)

Final code:-

```
public class NewBabyProfile extends Activity {

String GENDER = "Baby1Gender"; 

//Global declaration.
SharedPreferences babyOneGender;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);

    //Initializations inside onCreate() so no error.

    babyOneGender = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = babyOneGender.edit();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_baby_profile, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View genderSelection){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) genderSelection).isChecked();

    switch(genderSelection.getId()) {
        case R.id.gender_boy:
            if (checked)
                editor.putString("gender","boy").commit();
            break;

        case R.id.gender_girl:
            if (checked)
                editor.putString("gender","girl").commit();
            break;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Does this initialize them globally? It seems when I normally put them in onCreate they aren't defined when I try and use them in onRadioButtonClicked(). Sorry if I'm using some incorrect terms and thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated for global initializations :)

Comment: You declare the variables globally, but initialize them in onCreate(). This will not cause problem anymore :)

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why that didn't click for some reason but it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences babyOneGender = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

move initialization of babyOneGender & editor to onCreate:

```
    SharedPreferences babyOneGender;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);

        babyOneGender = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = babyOneGender.edit();
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! Is there any way to actually confirmed it edited the SharedPreferences file? I don't have a rooted phone so I can't view the XML file in /data.

Comment: you can test it on Android emulator, in which you have the root permission to view any files.